# for loop control 

Tags: c#

hey all
i want to know if there anyway that i control the for loop so if i push the button more than one time the program dose not freez and do the for loop again

Comment: Can you post your code - without it we can't really say what's going on.

Comment: You will have to work a little hardware than that. First of all try to describe the problem so we can all understand it, also specify which language/platform/framework you're using and a bit of code wouldn't hurt either :)

Comment: I think we need a little more info. What button (Keyboard, Windows.Forms, ASP.Net, ...), and what happens in the loop?

Answer (score 4):

Not if the for loop is running on the UI thread.  What's happening is that you are blocking the UI thread from processing the message pump, so the applications is unresponsive (i.e., it "hangs".)

If you need to run some relatively expensive operation in a tight loop like that just do so on a separate thread.  Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.  That class exposes a few events that makes it really simple to launch an operation on another thread.  You can set a cancel flag from the UI thread that can be checked inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your for loop is executing synchronously, it should not be a problem.

If it executes asynchronously, you can maintain a flag to avoid a concurrent execution.

Also, it will be very helpful if you post your code and provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's a problem because it is a long running operation on the UI thread, i.e., a button click won't be processed until that loop completes.

Comment: @Ed S.: By `it should not be a problem` i meant it should not do it again. And how do you know it is a long running operation. OP does not mention that.

Comment: OP says that the application "freezes", so obviously it is a long running operation that is tying up the UI thread.

Comment: Although, upon reading it again, he says "do the for loop again", so I see what you were getting at now.  Poorly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the loop on a background thread. Write the loop such that it exits when a WaitHandle is signaled. When the button is pushed again, just signal the wait handle to exit the loop.